# Program to hide the cursor on a running X.org server

Tags: rust, x11

I have a [use case](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/726059/147375) where I need to programmatically hide the cursor on a running X.org server.
While the suggested C progam works, I wanted to learn a bit about the X.org API and get some practice with rust. Hence I implemented an equivalent [program](https://github.com/homeinfogmbh/xhidecursor) that hides the cursor on an X.org server in Rust:

`Cargo.toml`

```
[package]
name = "xhidecursor"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"

# See more keys and their definitions at https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/manifest.html

[dependencies]
clap = { version = "4.0.23", features = ["derive"] }
ctrlc = "3.2.3"
x11 = { version = "2.20.1", features =["xlib", "xfixes"] }
```

`src/lib.rs`

```rust
use std::ffi::{c_char, CString};
use x11::xfixes::XFixesHideCursor;
use x11::xlib::{self, XDefaultRootWindow, XOpenDisplay, XSync};

pub struct Display<'a> {
    display: &'a mut xlib::Display,
}

impl<'a> Display<'a> {
    pub fn open(name: Option<impl Into<String>>) -> Option<Self> {
        match name {
            Some(name) => match CString::new(name.into()) {
                Ok(name) => Self::open_raw(name.as_ptr() as *const c_char),
                Err(_) => None,
            },
            None => Self::open_raw(&0),
        }
    }

    fn open_raw(display: *const c_char) -> Option<Self> {
        unsafe { XOpenDisplay(display).as_mut() }.map(|display| Self { display })
    }

    pub fn default_root_window(&mut self) -> u64 {
        unsafe { XDefaultRootWindow(self.display) }
    }

    pub fn hide_cursor(&mut self, window: u64) {
        unsafe { XFixesHideCursor(self.display, window) }
    }

    pub fn sync(&mut self, discard: bool) {
        match unsafe { XSync(self.display, discard as i32) } {
            1 => (),
            _ => unreachable!("XSync always returns 1."),
        }
    }
}
```

`src/main.rs`:

```rust
use clap::Parser;
use ctrlc::set_handler;
use std::process::exit;
use std::sync::atomic::{AtomicBool, Ordering};
use std::sync::Arc;
use std::thread::sleep;
use std::time::Duration;
use xhidecursor::Display;

#[derive(Parser)]
#[clap(about, author, version)]
struct Args {
    #[clap(short, long, name = "display", default_value = None)]
    pub display: Option<String>,
}

fn main() {
    let args = Args::parse();
    let running = Arc::new(AtomicBool::new(true));
    let is_running = running.clone();
    set_handler(move || {
        running.store(false, Ordering::SeqCst);
    })
    .expect("Error setting Ctrl-C handler.");

    match Display::open(args.display) {
        Some(mut display) => {
            let root = display.default_root_window();
            display.hide_cursor(root);
            display.sync(true);
        }
        None => {
            eprintln!("Cannot open display.");
            exit(1);
        }
    }

    while is_running.load(Ordering::SeqCst) {
        sleep(Duration::from_secs(1));
    }
}
```

How can I improve my code?