# Idiomatic Rust API to X11 displays

Tags: rust, api, x11

I am currently implementing a native Rust API to X11, especially around the `XDisplay` for a [related project](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/281475/program-to-hide-the-cursor-on-a-running-x-org-server).
I chose an object-oriented approach:

```rust
use crate::util::discard_const_1;
use std::ffi::{c_char, CString};
use x11::xlib::{
    self, Window, XActivateScreenSaver, XAddExtension, XAddHost, XAddHosts, XAddToSaveSet,
    XDefaultRootWindow, XExtCodes, XHostAddress, XOpenDisplay, XSync,
};

#[cfg(feature = "xfixes")]
use x11::xfixes::XFixesHideCursor;

pub struct Display<'a> {
    display: &'a mut xlib::Display,
}

impl<'a> Display<'a> {
    pub fn open(name: Option<impl Into<String>>) -> Option<Self> {
        match name {
            Some(name) => match CString::new(name.into()) {
                Ok(name) => Self::open_raw(name.as_ptr()),
                Err(_) => None,
            },
            None => Self::open_raw(&0),
        }
    }

    fn open_raw(display: *const c_char) -> Option<Self> {
        unsafe { XOpenDisplay(display).as_mut() }.map(|display| Self { display })
    }

    pub fn activate_screen_saver(&mut self) {
        discard_const_1(
            unsafe { XActivateScreenSaver(self.display) },
            "XActivateScreenSaver",
        )
    }

    pub fn add_extension(&mut self) -> XExtCodes {
        unsafe { *XAddExtension(self.display) }
    }

    pub fn add_host(&mut self, address: &mut XHostAddress) {
        discard_const_1(unsafe { XAddHost(self.display, address) }, "XAddHost")
    }

    pub fn add_hosts(&mut self, address: &mut XHostAddress, n: i32) {
        discard_const_1(unsafe { XAddHosts(self.display, address, n) }, "XAddHosts")
    }

    pub fn default_root_window(&mut self) -> Window {
        unsafe { XDefaultRootWindow(self.display) }
    }

    pub fn add_to_save_set(&mut self, window: Window) {
        discard_const_1(
            unsafe { XAddToSaveSet(self.display, window) },
            "XAddToSaveSet",
        )
    }

    // TODO: implement all xlib functions that take a display as first argument as methods.

    pub fn sync(&mut self, discard: bool) {
        discard_const_1(unsafe { XSync(self.display, discard as i32) }, "XSync")
    }
}

#[cfg(feature = "xfixes")]
impl<'a> Display<'a> {
    pub fn hide_cursor(&mut self, window: Window) {
        unsafe { XFixesHideCursor(self.display, window) }
    }
}
```

Many of the X* functions always return `1`, which the caller does not need.
Therefore I chose to return `()` from my functions in this case instead.
In order to not write the same code all over again, I implemented the following function:

```rust
#[inline]
pub(crate) fn discard_const_1(retval: i32, name: &str) {
    match retval {
        1 => (),
        _ => unreachable!("{} always returns 1.", name),
    }
}
```

Is this a good / acceptable solution? I am still pretty new to Rust and somehow managed to avoid writing macros up until now, but I have a gut feeling, that a macro might do a better job, than an inline function in my use case.
Is there a better way to convert from the constant `1`s to `()` in my library functions?

**NB**: The implementation of the API does not yet cover all of `xlib`'s functionality, but the API *works* and *is being used* by a program.

Comment: Please [edit] your question so that the title describes the *purpose* of the code, rather than its *mechanism*.  We really need to understand the motivational context to give good reviews.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
pub struct Display<'a> {
    display: &'a mut xlib::Display,
}
```

This bit is problematic. A borrow makes sense if your struct is holding references to data which is borrowed from somewhere else. But that's not what's going on. It seems rather that your `Display` struct owns the pointer to `xlib::Display`. You should really hold a raw pointer not a reference.
You might want to use `std::ptr::NonNull` to signal that the pointer is not null. Additionally, you should implement a drop function to call `XCloseDisplay` when your struct is dropped.

```
pub fn open(name: Option<impl Into<String>>) -> Option<Self> {
```

If I understand correctly, if you get `NULL` back from `XOpenDisplay` its an error. This function should probably return a `Result` to indicate that failure is an error.

```
#[inline]
pub(crate) fn discard_const_1(retval: i32, name: &str) {
    match retval {
        1 => (),
        _ => unreachable!("{} always returns 1.", name),
    }
}
```

The other response suggest that you should return `Result` for errors instead of `panic`ing. Generally speaking, I'd agree with them. However, it seems that xlib doesn't provide useful error handling mechanics. Most errors will come back asynchronously and by default will terminate the application. In light of that, I think panicing isn't a bad strategy.

However I'd:

1. Call it something like `check_status`
2. Check for 0, since the documentation states that errors return 0
3. Use a generic panic, not unreachable. Its panicing because it got an error, not because its unreachable
4. Not put the name in the error message. This complicates all your calls because you have to pass the name, and it should very rarely matter (since these functions don't practically return errors). And if you need to know where the error comes from, you want to look at a stack trace anyways which will tell you.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you must distinguish between return values that represent a Status to those that return something else. This may not be immediately obvious from the function declaration, unfortunately. Anyway, you should make sure that the returned value is a Status somehow, possibly by looking at the source code.

Note that you cannot determine from the code if the value will be returned differently in future versions of the software. All future versions have to do is to keep to the contract, and nothing prevents a future developer to change the way that a function operates internally.

From the [X documentation](https://www.x.org/releases/current/doc/libX11/libX11/libX11.html#Errors):

> Some functions return Status, an integer error indication. If the function fails, it returns a zero. If the function returns a status of zero, it has not updated the return arguments.

This also shows other errors:

- it is not that the function returns `1`, it returns a value different from zero. So you should match zero (for false / an error) and otherwise continue.
- `discard_const_1` is a bad function name, it should say something like `handle_status`: currently it describes syntax rather than semantics.

Now for the implementation: you perform an `unreachable` which indicates that the code should be unreachable. But this is incorrect: the code **is** reachable, depending on the status. That would be akin to saying that the C-code of X.org can never fail. Obviously it can, otherwise there would be no reason to ever return a Status code.

Furthermore, `unreachable` will result in a panic. That's not good for code that - for instance - activates a screen saver. If it fails than this is bad, but it is certainly not a good reason to create an unrecoverable error. Instead you could return a `Result`.

As this seems to be a relatively low level wrapper library, I would try and find a way to propagate the Status codes (in case of success) and possibly an error description on failure. Reading through the X docs, it seems you may have to supply your own error handling routine for retrieving the error description.

For a higher level library you might want to return a lower amount of information.

---

Note that I'm not a Rust expert, so I will not propose a specific format of `Result` to return. The given review is largely agnostic to the PL.

Comment: Thank you for your review. But the functions in question actually *always* return zero. I actually *did* check  the source code for each of the functions, where I discard a constant return value of one. E.g.: https://github.com/freedesktop/xorg-libX11/blob/5faa8dc0b364f55f19034c370436074646d9ad54/src/Sync.c#L35. Hence all other return values actually *are* unreachable in those cases.

Comment: This may sound strange to you, but this is not enough. You're programming against an API that has functions that return a value. Your code would only be correct assuming that no errors are returned at any place in the code, *now and in the future*. To me, the whole idea that functions can never error - especially when it comes to things as launching a screen saver - is unbelievable anyway (this is why I prefer languages that include exceptions).